# breadcrumb woocommerce show product categories?

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I'm really struggling with this so I was hoping someone could help me.  I'm using woocommerce plugin, the products for the breadcrumbs only show the main category of a certain product, I would like it so that it could show the sub categories as well.  For example, I would like it to be Bottoms > Leggings > Skirts.  The woocoommerce breadcrumb code I have now only shows Bottoms:

```
<?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>
```

Is there anyone who might know how I can add this so that it shows the trail of sub categories in woo commerce category pages?

Thanks